# WP Search page posts count conditional display based on post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to implement a conditional display of number of posts (post count) on the search page based on the post type.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
  if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type == 'MY_POST_TYPE' ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
  };
} );
```

Where I could use `is_post_type == 'MY_POST_TYPE'` to specify the post type... I've been looking around but couldn't manage to find an answer... It's a bit troubling because it sound like a basic feature... Any ideas ?

**EDIT 1:**
Something like this where there is a different number of post being displayed based on the post type

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type == 'MY_POST_TYPE_1' ) {
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
} elseif ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type == 'MY_POST_TYPE_2' ) {
$query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
};
} );
```

Comment: Does your search page only show your CPTs and you want to limit the total number or results? Or is your search not limited by post type and you only want to show certain number of each post type?

Comment: Hi @FluffyKitten , I want to show a certain number, DIFFERENT on each CPTs

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear! Does the same search shows a mix of different CPTs, or does the search only include one type of CPT but you would like different numbers for different searches?

Comment: @FluffyKitten , No mix of CPTs on search page. When a user search for CPT_1 it should return only 1 post per page, if user search for CPT_2 then should return 10 post per page (something like that) ... See EDIT 1

Comment: OK, I understand now, thanks! In that case, you are going about it the right way so we just need to find the bug :) What template is the search happening in?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words! the search is happening in the default search page template... (didn't know i could use an other template to run the search query tbh...) Do you have idea? My first thought was to use `'CPT_1' === get_post_type()` but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.. it's just getting ignored

Comment: You could change the template to a custom template in functions.php, or create a custom one. So when someone does a search, how do they choose the CPT to search - do they have an option to filter by post type for example, and does this get added to the WP_Query? The default search page isn't for a specific post type, so we need to understand how this is added to the query before we can work out how it can be changed conditionally. If you could show us the code that does this (e.g. in the search form or the search page) it would help.

Comment: I'm simply using hidden inputs to specify the required CPT. Depending on which page, the form is using different hidden inputs. (nothing fancy on that side) ... I just can't figure out how to target the CPTs by names/slug on the function side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221050/discussion-between-fluffykitten-and-amarinediary).

Comment: I've added an answer with lots of info, but I haven't checked any of the code so let me know if you try any of it and there are problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add additional conditional query args based on the query CPT, we can do this using `pre_get_posts` hook, as you are doing.

### Check if the query is for a CPT

We'll create a custom function that will hook into this action and check if the `$query` contains the CPT, and add the extra args if it does. As you came up with also, this will work:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_cpt_query_args');

function add_cpt_query_args( $query ) {
    // If this isn't the main search query on the site, then do nothing.
    if( is_admin() || !$query->is_search() || !$query->is_main_query() )
        return;
    // Check if the query is for any of our CPTs
    if (in_array ( $query->get( post_type'), array('YOUR_CPT_SLUG', 'ANOTHER_CPT') ) ){
        // set the args for this CPT
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
    }
}
```

### Checking for Multiple CPTs and with Different Query Args

As you want to do this for multiple CPTs and give them different args (e.g. `posts_per_page`), you would have to add a separate `if` for each in the code above.

**A more flexible and maintainable way** to do this would be to use an array to keep all the query args info for each CPT in an array. This means:

- we can simply loop through this to use add our query args - no adding extra `if` checks for every CPT to check
- we can add as many or as few query args as we need for each CPT (e.g. `pages_per_post`, `order_by` etc), each CPT can have different args, and don't have to hardcode them into the code, or manually check if we have a value for them.

**We can do that with this code** - there is a full explanation of how it works below
(Note - this is untested but the basic logic is there!):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_cpt_query_args');

function add_cpt_query_args( $query ) {

    // If this isn't the main search query on the site, then do nothing.
    if( is_admin() || !$query->is_search() || !$query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // As you want to do this for multiple CPTS, a handy way to do this is set up all the info in an array
    $CPT_args['qcm'] = array('posts_per_page'=> 1, 'orderby' => 'rand');
    $CPT_args['anotherCPT'] = array('posts_per_page'=> 5, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order => 'ASC'');

    // Now check each CPT in our array to see if this query is for it
    foreach ($CPT_args as $cpt => $query_args ){
        if (in_array ( $query->get( post_type'), array($cpt) ) ){

            // this query is for a CPT in our array, so add our query args to the query
            foreach ($query_args as $arg => $value )
                $query->set( $arg, $value );
         }
    }
}
```

### How this Works

**1. Check that this is the main search query on the main site** - if it isn't (and we have no other conditions), the cleanest way is to simply end the function at this point, then we're not trying to keep lots of code inside an `if`

```
if( is_admin() || !$query->is_search() || !$query->is_main_query() )
    return;
```

---

**2. Set up your CPT arguments in an array** - as you want to do this for multiple CPTs, the easiest way to do this is store all the info in an array that we can them simply use in a loop.

- We'll use an array called `$CPT_args` in this example, and add an entry for each CPT we want to check for, with the CPT name as the key.
- We'll use another array as the value, and this will have all the args you want to add to the `$query` for this CPT, e.g.

```
    $CPT_args['qcm'] = array('posts_per_page'=> 1, 'orderby' => 'rand');
```

Using this array keeps all the args info together in one place and makes it easy to add or remove more CPT conditions without affecting the main code that affects the query.

---

**3. Check if the `$query` is for any of out CPTS** by loop through our array and checking the query `post_type` against the keys in our `$CPT_args` array:

```
foreach ($CPT_args as $cpt => $query_args ){
    if (in_array ( $query->get( post_type'), array($cpt) ) ){
        ... 
    }
}
```

---

**4. Add the query args for the CPT to `$query`** if this query is for that CPT. We can simply look through our array of args and add them to the `$query`.

```
    foreach ($queryargs as $arg => $value )
        $query->set( $arg, $value );
```

---

Comment: If I could buy you a coffee, I would!